# Layers not aligning in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have two layers, one of points (locations of fruit trees) and one of Atlanta zip codes, in ArcMap 10, but the layers are not aligning. The fruit trees are in a corner and the map is in the middle top.

The fruit points were successfully converted to a shp file from a csv file.

The two layers have the same projected coordinate system NAD_1983_StatePlane_Georgia_West_FIPS_1002_Feet

and the same geographic coordinate system
GCS_North_American_1983

I thought the error would be that the systems didn't match up, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The two datasets which are the sources of your two layers may have the same coordinate system but they may not both have been captured in the same coordinate system.

You say that the "fruit points" came from a CSV file so my immediate suspicion is that they may have come from a GPS and be in WGS84 datum rather than NAD83.

If the values in that CSV are in decimal degrees then that would add weight to my suspicion.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely sounds possible. How would I go about making it work then?

Comment: @Caroline I think you should research/ask that as a separate Question in which you include a graphic of your CSV.